# Google Colab: Run all cells until the current one

Tags: google-colaboratory

I would like to know how to run all cells (from the beginning of the notebook) and stop at the cell that's selected (do not want to run ALL cells..) on Google-Colab.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

Just select the cell and click on `Runtime > Run before` in the toolbar at the top of the notebook. `Runtime > Run before` runs all the cells from the beginning of the notebook until the selected cell (not included).

Another way is to select all the cells you want to run and click on `Runtime > Run selection`.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks ninjin! Exactly what I looked for, I could also see that `CTRL+F8` achieves the same

Answer (score 5):

To run all cells above you can use this shortcut: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F8</kbd>.

Or manually: *Runtime* > *Run before*.