# how to run until cell selected INCLUDED in google colab?

Tags: google-colaboratory

how to run until cell selected ***INCLUDED*** in google colab?

The only thing I've found is this one:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/58959214/15416347
but here the cell selected is NOT INCLUDED

Comment: What about adding an empty cell after your mentioned cell and run until it in "not included" mode?

Comment: it's a good workaround thanks,
I was hoping there was a shortcut to do it directly